GitHub still showing commits ahead after commits were merged into main repo
My pull request was successfully merged, however my forked repository is still showing that 5 commits are ahead, after those commits were merged in my PR.
Any idea on how to get everything equalized again? This can be a problem for future pull requests where the past commits show up in the pull request.
Tried: various commands from other similar questions on stackoverflow, such as:
git fetch --all
git push --force upstream/master:master
git push --force
git fetch upstream

Any commands with upstream shows UPSTREAM as an unknown repository.
fatal: 'upstream/master:master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Expected: everything to equalize, between the forked repo and the original repository.
Actually resulted: Nothing happened to any repository from what I could tell.

What's the output of git remote -v on the fork? (You can redact details of paths if you want, but don't redact the first column.)

The output is:
origin  https://github.com/overlappingd/wiki.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/overlappingd/wiki.git (push)

I am also using GitKraken Desktop, FYI

That's why you can't push to upstream - you don't have any remote named upstream. If origin is the GitHub copy of your fork, then you can use git remote add upstream $URL (where $URL is the URL for the main repo) to create an upstream associated with that main repo.

Looks like the  bsmg/wiki (master) was merged to your repo's master.
base repository: bsmg/wiki (master) <--- head repository: overlappingd/bsmg-wiki (master)
From a github ui this is what the correct merges should look like.

I cannot sync my forked repo, as it is not behind the upstream original repository in commits, rather it is ahead with commits that were already merged. git pull does nothing, and so does git reset --soft HEAD~1, just nothing, except for putting 1 commit in the GitHub and not my local, and that is when my pull request was merged: "Merge branch bsmg:master into master"

Looking at the pr https://github.com/bsmg/wiki/commit/2ace11c1c326209ae793218a98859cdaa923f8e6. It doesnt look like your branch was merged

The PR was definitely merged: here's the link to it: https://github.com/bsmg/wiki/pull/611
And as you can tell from my branch, it shows 5 commits ahead, and those commits are the ones merged.

This merge https://github.com/bsmg/wiki/commit/2ace11c1c326209ae793218a98859cdaa923f8e6 is different from this merge https://github.com/bsmg/wiki/pull/611. The commit numbers are different

I'm not sure what that commit is, but there's still 4 commits from that PR that were merged, but still show that they are ahead in my fork repository.

you can do a git rebase, but you have to be careful to remove the commit causing the issue. Look up how you use it.
this commit https://github.com/bsmg/wiki/commit/2ace11c1c326209ae793218a98859cdaa923f8e6 is what might be causing the issues.
Or If you merged your commits and it looks like they are there, one option could be to delete your local files and forked repo. Then fork from the base repo, clone to your local and set it up all over again.

When you did the "sync" you probably merged bsmg:master to your repo's master

Managed to fix it, first removed the Merge commit from my local on GitKraken, then forced pushed and discarded changes on GitHub so it would be up to date, and then delete and reclone my local branch
